# Adobe Premiere Pro CS6 - No video preview/playback/output

Tags: adobe

I have this really bad issue, because I can't find, how to solve it. As you can see, I've loaded some random video, but there's nothing showing. Maybe it has something in common, that I'm using Widows Insider builds.
[This is screenshot i've taken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TENjb.png)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you clicked on timeline bar after dargging to timeline. Click once again on timeline or in frame appeared in ***PINK COLOR*** (in your screen shot). See whether Preview is visible or not. If still not, reply. I hope it will solve your problem.